# What are(some of the)top level(under /) directories meant for in file system os Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have read `man hier` (`info hier` in fact). But it seems a bit old(Correct me if I am wrong). There are many directories, which are not mentioned in the manual.
Eg

```
/sys
/selinux
/lost+found
```

I have seen these on `Ubuntu` and `CentOs5` versions. Also I am not sure about the difference between `/media` and `/mnt`, though my guess is `/mnt` can be used for mounting any filesystem, and `/media` is meant to be used as mount points as only for (removable) media. Though I am not convinced that this difference is enough for `/media` deserving a separate directory, rather than being a special case for `/mnt`. What am I missing here? So can someone shed some light on these(above) directories in the filesystems (especially in terms of their intended usage & practical usage, any tricks & and advantages for having them.)?

**Note**: I have read similar questions but haven't found anything related to above directories.

Comment: As for your "/mnt vs /media"-question, see http://superuser.com/a/417180.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it seems a bit old(Correct me if I am wrong).

The [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) changes very slowly, so that's not really a problem per se.

```
/sys
/selinux
```

These are similar to `/proc`, but for [sysfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) and selinuxfs instead of procfs.

```
/lost+found
```

This is where loose (i.e. allocated but not in any directory, an error condition) files found by `fsck` are sent so that the sysadmin can look through them to see if they're needed.

> though my guess is `/mnt` can be used for mounting any filesystem, and `/media` is meant to be used as mount points as only for (removable) media.

Correct.

> Though I am not convinced that this difference is enough for `/media` deserving a separate directory, rather than being a special case for `/mnt`.

Opinions vary, and everyone seems to have a unique one.

Comment: Can you explain (or point me to the explanation of) /proc?

Comment: @0xc0de: It's in the Linux kernel documentation, under `Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt`.

Comment: I had a glance through it, but couldn't link /sys & /selinux to /proc :-S